# Where to put my xUnit tests for an F# assembly?

Tags: f#, tdd, projects-and-solutions, xunit.net

I'm working on my first 'real' F# assembly, and trying to do things right.

I've managed to get xUnit working too, but currently my test module is inside the same assembly. This bothers me a bit, because it means I'll be shipping an assembly where nearly half the code (and 80% of the API) is test methods.

What is the 'right' way to do this? If I put the tests in another assembly, I think that means I have to expose internals that I'd rather keep private.

I know that in C# there is a friend mechanism for tests (if that's the right terminology), is there an equivalent in F#?

Alternatively, can anyone point me to an example project where this is being done 'properly'?

Comment: Hehe, wanted to upvote this, but for some reason it wouldn't work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use the InternalsVisibleTo-Attribute to expose your internals to some other assembly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(VS.100).aspx

*EDIT*

If your assembly is signed, you will also need to sign the Friend assembly, and provide the public key in the InternalsVisibleTo attribute:

```
[<assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ProcessorTests, PublicKey=0024000004800...)")>]
```

Comment: Hm, yes, that's the 'friend mechanism' I was thinking of. Useful associated links: http://thevalerios.net/matt/2009/01/assembly-information-for-f-libraries/ & http://geekswithblogs.net/AnneBougie/archive/2008/10/01/internalsvisibleto-with-strongly-type-assemblies.aspx

Comment: Can't get the compiler to accept concatenated string for my PublicKey though - makes things a bit ugly, but appears to work all the same.